# converting from xml to rss 2.0

Tags: rss, xml

I am working with a Yahoo store owner trying to submit inventory as a data feed; I can grab the data from the website in the form of an XML file by using a Yahoo store convention of: http://site.com/objinfo.xml, but that has too much information that I don't need in the product feed. I am trying to turn this XML file into a RSS 2.0 format with only specific fields from the XML file.

Would it be better to use a script to populate the file or a specific program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write an [XSLT stylesheet](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to convert it, then use either an XSLT library for a programming language or a tool such as `xsltproc` to process it.

Comment: cool, so the XSLT stylesheet is like the template for the product file, in this case RSS? and i will process the xml file with the XSLT template through a language with appropriate library or use a tool?

Comment: That is the essentials of it, yes.